# How to find and replace the first null value per row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, isnull, sql-null

I have a table with around 20 columns and over 5000 rows. For each row, I am trying to replace the first null value with the string `"end"`.

What I have:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* Create a table called dataframe */
CREATE TABLE dataframe(id integer primary key, col1 text, col2 text, col3 text, col4 text, col5 text);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO dataframe VALUES(1,'a',null,null,null,null);
INSERT INTO dataframe VALUES(2,'a','b',null,null,null);
INSERT INTO dataframe VALUES(3,'a','c','d','e', null);
INSERT INTO dataframe VALUES(4,'a','c','d',null, null);
INSERT INTO dataframe VALUES(5,'a','c',null, null, null);
COMMIT;

/* Display all the records from the table */
SELECT * FROM dataframe;
```

What I need:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* Create a table called dataframe */
CREATE TABLE dataframe(id integer primary key, col1 text, col2 text, col3 text, col4 text, col5 text);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO dataframe VALUES(1,'a','end',null,null,null);
INSERT INTO dataframe VALUES(2,'a','b','end',null,null);
INSERT INTO dataframe VALUES(3,'a','c','d','e', 'end');
INSERT INTO dataframe VALUES(4,'a','c','d','end', null);
INSERT INTO dataframe VALUES(5,'a','c','end', null, null);
COMMIT;

/* Display all the records from the table */
SELECT * FROM dataframe;
```

Can I use `FIRST_VALUE()` on row level?

Comment: It's postgresql.

Comment: What do do in case of a `NULL` somewhere in the middle? For instance `VALUES (2,'a','b',null,'d',null);`

Comment: @RobertKock Good question! But, such a case would not occur. The table has been built in such a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple `case` expressions are probably the simplest method:

```
select df.id,
       (case when df.col1 is null
             then 'end' else df.col1
        end) as col1,
       (case when df.col1 is not null and df.col2 is null
             then 'end' else df.col2
        end) as col2,
       (case when df.col1 is not null and df.col2 is not null and df.col3 is null
             then 'end' else df.col3
        end) as col3,
       . . .
from dataframe df;
```

If you want to actually *change* the data, then this is easily adapted to an `update`.